# I'm on a 2MBPS internet connection but i want to check a website like i'm on a 256 KBPS connection on same PC?

Tags: windows, performance, optimization, xhtml, testing-strategies

Does anyone know how to test? I'm on Windows XP? and Firefox , IE7 installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the similar question [Firefox plugin to simulate slow internet connection or limit bandwidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth) and its [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth/473489#473489) to find the FF plugin [Firefox Throttle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917) and IE Plugin [Internet Explorer Throttle](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/IEThrottle.aspx).

If you have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) installed in FF, take also the [YSlow plugin](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) into consideration. It gives you a lot of information on the performance issues with your pages.

Comment: i installed firefox throttle but i think it's not working, site is opening with same speed

Comment: Did you try to set the bandwith in the options even to something very very low and is it turned on in the status panel?